# Blank page when executing a database query?

Tags: php, database, fix-my-code

**What's wrong with this code? I'm getting a blank page for this?**

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);

if( $user->username == 'THE_USER_1' )
{
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('username'));
    ->from($db->quoteName('#table_name#'));
    ->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->username));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->loadResult();

if($result) { 
   echo "<p> You have already filled the form.</p>";
}
else {
    // continue to form page
}
elseif( $user->username == 'THE_USER_2' )
{
    // some code 
}
else
{
    echo "<p> Sorry, you can't access this page.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: A blank page generally means that there are PHP errors. I would highly recommend displaying errors while writing new code. The system will highlight exact lines where you are missing things like brackets and semicolons.

Comment: @DavidFritsch .. the code is almost fixed! check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing a closing brackets in your `if` statement. Also, you are carrying on the database query having ended the previous line with a semi-colon. I don't know what you have also done when defining the database table, but you should replace `#table_name#` with `#__table_name`.

Copy and paste the code below which includes the missing closing bracket, removal of additional semi-colons and correct table name:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);

if( $user->username == 'THE_USER_1' )
{
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('username'))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name'))
          ->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->username));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->loadResult();

    if($result) { 
       echo "<p> You have already filled the form.</p>";
    }
}
elseif( $user->username == 'THE_USER_2' )
{
    // some code 
}
elseif( $user->username !== 'THE_USER_1' || $user->username !== 'THE_USER_2' )
{
    echo "<p> Sorry, you can't access this page.</p>";
}
else 
{
    echo "display form";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: still getting a blank page?

Comment: even when i access the page as "THE_USER_2" , i still get a blank page?

Comment: I will need to do some tests when I get back from work.  Will report back soon

Comment: No issues Lodder! 
& btw thankyou, in advance. i know you'll find a solution to this problem. ;)

Comment: Ahh, you had an `elseif` **after** an `else` statement which isn't allowed. I've edited my code accordingly. Please try again

Comment: Hey lodder, the blank page is gone..The query gets executed perfectly..but it also echo's the last else statement..
`echo "<p> Sorry, you can't access this page.</p>";` .. What about that?

Comment: @Saibbyweb - Do you want that message to appear to guests only?

Comment: i want that message to appear to all the users except "THE_USER_1" & "THE_USER_2"

Comment: @Saibbyweb - I have updated the last bit of code, please try now

Comment: still the same?

Comment: Ok let me have a test later on.

Comment: hmm..please do. :)

Comment: @Saibbyweb - I've updated the answer again. I think this should be what you're looking for now

Comment: i this you're close! When the logged in user doesn't match with username in database table, it doesn't echo "display form" statement.. apart from this..everythink works fine.

Comment: Im still very confused as to how you want to structure this whole `if` `else` method. You haven't really explained in your question **exactly** what you want therefore we are simply going round in circles with me editing my answer constantly. I have answered you initial question which was the issue with the blank screen and helped as much I can with the structure. Have a look at the code, have a think and maybe try yourself.

Comment: i figured out! thankyou..you answer helped alot!